# Confused on how to properly work on / install Spring files

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to set up a simple restful API on my Linode server for my Android app to communicate with. I am new to the area of server software and setup.

So I have this guide:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#scratch

Am I developing this project on my local machine and then, at the end, somehow moving it all over to the server? I am confused how I "install the Spring framework" on the server, even with this guide, or what exactly I need to do to set things up.

Am I supposed to create the whole thing locally, generate the jar, upload that jar to the server, and just run it directly there and it'll handle the rest?

Answer (score 0):

As this is a spring boot application, you will have two possibilities:
The default is to just build the projects jar and run it on the target system, because [spring boot allows you to embed a tomcat container into your project](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html).
The second one would be to package your project into a .war file (`packaging` property in the `pom.xml`) and deploy this .war file in a [tomcat container you previously installed on the server](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html).

EDIT:
You don't have to "install the spring framework on your server". You app is based on the spring framework, that's it. Just build your app (with maven or gradle according to the tutorial) and run the .jar on the server (`java -jar yourapp.jar`). As there is an embedded, pre-configured tomcat included in the spring-boot framework, it will run the tomcat, deploy your app and run the app for you.

Comment: Can I build this Spring app in Android Studio or do I need to use something like IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: i think it's make more sense to use something else than Android Studio. I bet it would work, but it's specialized to develop android apps. Use eclipse or intelliJ instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand that spring is an application, to connect to that application you need any server to deploy your application like Tomcat, GlassFish, etc.

Once you have your own server, you need to export your spring.jar or spring.war to the server to make it running.

Then when the app is running you can connect to that using the URLNameOfYourServer/YourSpringApp

Another thing is when you are using STS, Eclipse, Netbeans, Intellij those IDES uses embedded server to deploy and test your app.

If you want to create your own server, make sure you have installed java and tomcat then deploy your app.

Comment: Well yes, but it's not forbidden to use the embedded tomcat in production. Many people do so successfully. It just depends on what you need. If you only want one app per container anyway, the embedded tomcat is a nice feature to use, here.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the online guide I linked above that I need to install Tomcat?

Comment: I use an easy way with pivotal cloud foundy [Link Here](https://pivotal.io/platform) look at the starter guide for spring apps if your are new configuring web servers this should be the best choice for you.

Comment: @IvanLynch This ultimately redirects to the same tutorial pages I already linked

Comment: Check this [Host your application in Linode](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/hosting-a-website), install apache tomcat following the guide. Once apache is installed copy your war file to webapps directory of Apache tomcat